# MLflow remote execution on databricks from windows creates an invalid dbfs path

Tags: databricks, mlflow

I'm researching the use of MLflow as part of our data science initiatives and I wish to set up a minimum working example of remote execution on databricks from windows.

However, when I perform the remote execution a path is created locally on windows in the MLflow package which is sent to databricks. This path specifies the upload location of the '.tar.gz' file corresponding to the Github repo containing the MLflow Project. In cmd this has a combination of '\' and '/', but on databricks there are no separators at all in this path, which raises the 'rsync: No such file or directory (2)' error.

To be more general, I reproduced the error using an MLflow standard example and following this [guide](https://docs.databricks.com/applications/mlflow/projects.html) from databricks. The MLflow example is the [sklearn_elasticnet_wine](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/tree/master/examples/sklearn_elasticnet_wine), but I had to add a default value to a parameter so I forked it and the MLproject which can be executed remotely can be found at ([forked repo](https://github.com/aestene/mlflow/tree/master/examples/sklearn_elasticnet_wine)).

The Project can be executed remotely by the following command (assuming a databricks instance has been set up)

```
mlflow run https://github.com/aestene/mlflow#examples/sklearn_elasticnet_wine -b databricks -c db-clusterconfig.json --experiment-id <insert-id-here>
```

where "db-clusterconfig.json" correspond to the cluster to set up in databricks and is in this example set to

```
{
    "autoscale": {
        "min_workers": 1,
        "max_workers": 2
    },
    "spark_version": "5.5.x-scala2.11",
    "node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2",
    "driver_node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2",
    "ssh_public_keys": [],
    "custom_tags": {},
    "spark_env_vars": {
        "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/databricks/python3/bin/python3"
    }
}
```

When running the project remotely, this is the output in cmd:

```
2019/10/04 10:09:50 INFO mlflow.projects: === Fetching project from https://github.com/aestene/mlflow#examples/sklearn_elasticnet_wine into C:\Users\ARNTS\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2qzdyq9_ ===
2019/10/04 10:10:04 INFO mlflow.projects.databricks: === Uploading project to DBFS path /dbfs\mlflow-experiments\3947403843428882\projects-code\aa5fbb4769e27e1be5a983751eb1428fe998c3e65d0e66eb9b4c77355076f524.tar.gz ===
2019/10/04 10:10:05 INFO mlflow.projects.databricks: === Finished uploading project to /dbfs\mlflow-experiments\3947403843428882\projects-code\aa5fbb4769e27e1be5a983751eb1428fe998c3e65d0e66eb9b4c77355076f524.tar.gz ===
2019/10/04 10:10:05 INFO mlflow.projects.databricks: === Running entry point main of project https://github.com/aestene/mlflow#examples/sklearn_elasticnet_wine on Databricks ===
2019/10/04 10:10:06 INFO mlflow.projects.databricks: === Launched MLflow run as Databricks job run with ID 8. Getting run status page URL... ===
2019/10/04 10:10:18 INFO mlflow.projects.databricks: === Check the run's status at https://<region>.azuredatabricks.net/?o=<databricks-id>#job/8/run/1 ===
```

Where the DBFS path has a leading '/' before the remaining are '\'.

The command spins up a cluster in databricks and is ready to execute the job, but ends up with the following error message on the databricks side:

```
rsync: link_stat "/dbfsmlflow-experiments3947403843428882projects-codeaa5fbb4769e27e1be5a983751eb1428fe998c3e65d0e66eb9b4c77355076f524.tar.gz" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.1]
```

Where we can see the same path but without the '\' inserted. I narrowed down the creation of this path to this [file](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/master/mlflow/projects/databricks.py) in the MLflow Github repo, where the following code creates the path (line 133):

```py
dbfs_path = os.path.join(DBFS_EXPERIMENT_DIR_BASE, str(experiment_id),
                                     "projects-code", "%s.tar.gz" % tarfile_hash)
dbfs_fuse_uri = os.path.join("/dbfs", dbfs_path)
```

My current hypothesis is that `os.path.join()` in the first line joins the string together in a "windows fashion" such that they have backslashes. Then the following call to `os.path.join()` adds a '/'. The databricks file system is then unable to handle this path and something causes the 'tar.gz' file to not be properly uploaded or to be accessed at the wrong path.

It should also be mentioned that the project runs fine locally.

I'm running the following versions:

Windows 10

Python 3.6.8

MLflow 1.3.0 (also replicated the fault with 1.2.0)

Any feedback or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the catch, you're right that using `os.path.join` when working with DBFS paths is incorrect, resulting in a malformed path that breaks project execution. I've filed to https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/1926 track this, if you're interested in making a bugfix PR ([see the MLflow contributor guide for info on how to do this](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.rst)) to replace `os.path.join` here with `os.posixpath.join` I'd be happy to review :)

Comment: I will have a look next week!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for putting this issue.
I also encountered the same at windows 10.

I resolved this issue, with replacing all 'os.path' to 'posixpath' at 'databricks.py' file.
It worked perfectly fine for me.